# React Redux deleting item from array at specific index

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to delete an item in an array by accessing the id of the object within the array which I'm mapping to individual components.

I'm pretty sure that my reducer is properly configured, but I'm having trouble passing the id of the object to the action.  When I console.log the action payload I get `Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, …}`.

Here is the code

action:

```
  console.log(id)
  return {
    type: DELETE_QUOTE,
    payload: id
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
        return {
          ...state,
          generatedQuotes: state.generatedQuotes.filter(quote=>quote.id !== action.payload.id)
        }
```

container component:

```
{this.props.generatedQuotes.map((item, i) => 
                <div className="column is-half" key={i}>
                <QuoteCard
                  author={item.name} 
                  quote={item.quote} 
                  email={item.email} 
                  date={item.date}
                  id={item.id}
                  deleteQuote={this.props.deleteQuote}
                />
                </div>
          )}
```

mapDispatchToProps in container component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    generateQuote: () => dispatch(generateQuote()),
    deleteQuote: id => dispatch(deleteQuote(id))
  };
}
```

presentational component:

```
const QuoteCard = ({author, email, date, quote, id, deleteQuote}) => {
  return (
    <div className="box" key={date}>
      <article className="media">
        <div className="media-left">
          <figure className="image is-128x128">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png" alt="Mock" />
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div className="media-content">
          <div className="content">
            <p>
              <strong>{author}</strong>
              <small>{email}</small>
              <br />
              <small><em>{date}</em></small>
              <br />
              {quote}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <br />
      <div className="buttons">
        <button className="button is-success is-small" onClick={() => window.open(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="${quote}" Quote by: ${author}`)}>Tweet Quote</button>
        <button className="button is-danger is-small" onClick={(id) => deleteQuote(id)}>Delete Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Change `onClick={(id) => deleteQuote(id)}` to `onClick={() => deleteQuote(id)}`. Otherwise you'll use the event object as parameter to deleteQuote

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` is `action.payload`, so

```
return {
  ...state,
  generatedQuotes: state.generatedQuotes.filter(quote=> quote.id !== action.payload)
};
```